# Apache virtualhost servername by ip + documentroot

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony, ubuntu

I am trying to get this virtualhost working on apache + ubuntu. I want it to work without a real domainname but by ip and the path. It is now not getting activated. Is it possible to use the serverName like this or are only domain names valid?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
         serverName 37.35.66.98/just-do-it/
         DocumentRoot /var/www/html/just-do-it/web
         <Directory /var/www/html/just-do-it/web>
               AllowOverride All
               Order Allow,Deny
               Allow from All
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: IP address is valid, but URL-path is not It is valid. Try just `ServerName 37.35.66.98`

Answer (score 0):

Remove path portion from server name, then this should work

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
         serverName 37.35.66.98
         DocumentRoot /var/www/html/just-do-it/web
         <Directory /var/www/html/just-do-it/web>
               Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
               AllowOverride All
               Order Allow,Deny
               Allow from All
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

do not forget to add your server name in `/etc/hosts` file